# Change the Click Function to just Play

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

i have this 2 codes and want change the JS file.
Currently that's how it works: 
--> the animation starts only when you click in the navigation.

I want play the animation if my site is loaded but i don't finde the function to change the code.

you can find the animation here: https://tympanus.net/Development/ShapeOverlays/index3.html

Thank you so much.

html:

```
<div class="animation">
<svg class="shape-overlays" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<path class="shape-overlays__path"></path>
<path class="shape-overlays__path"></path>
<path class="shape-overlays__path"></path>
</svg>
</div>
```

JS-File:

```
setTimeout(() => document.body.classList.add('render'), 60);
class ShapeOverlays {
  constructor(elm) {
    this.elm = elm;
    this.path = elm.querySelectorAll('path');
    this.numPoints = 2;
    this.duration = 600;
    this.delayPointsArray = [];
    this.delayPointsMax = 0;
    this.delayPerPath = 200;
    this.timeStart = Date.now();
    this.isOpened = false;
    this.isAnimating = false;
  }

  toggle() {
    this.isAnimating = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.numPoints; i++) {
      this.delayPointsArray[i] = 0;
    }
    if (this.isOpened === false) {
      this.open();
    } else {
      this.close();
    }
  }



  open() {
    this.isOpened = true;
    this.elm.classList.add('is-opened');
    this.timeStart = Date.now();
    this.renderLoop();
  }



  close() {
    this.isOpened = false;
    this.elm.classList.remove('is-opened');
    this.timeStart = Date.now();
    this.renderLoop();
  }
  */


  updatePath(time) {
    const points = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.numPoints; i++) {
      const thisEase = this.isOpened ? 
                        (i == 1) ? ease.cubicOut : ease.cubicInOut:
                        (i == 1) ? ease.cubicInOut : ease.cubicOut;
      points[i] = thisEase(Math.min(Math.max(time - this.delayPointsArray[i], 0) / this.duration, 1)) * 100
    }

    let str = '';
    str += (this.isOpened) ? `M 0 0 V ${points[0]} ` : `M 0 ${points[0]} `;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.numPoints - 1; i++) {
      const p = (i + 1) / (this.numPoints - 1) * 100;
      const cp = p - (1 / (this.numPoints - 1) * 100) / 2;
      str += `C ${cp} ${points[i]} ${cp} ${points[i + 1]} ${p} ${points[i + 1]} `;
    }
    str += (this.isOpened) ? `V 0 H 0` : `V 100 H 0`;
    return str;
  }



  render() {
    if (this.isOpened) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.path.length; i++) {
        this.path[i].setAttribute('d', this.updatePath(Date.now() - (this.timeStart + this.delayPerPath * i)));
      }
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.path.length; i++) {
        this.path[i].setAttribute('d', this.updatePath(Date.now() - (this.timeStart + this.delayPerPath * (this.path.length - i - 1))));
      }
    }
  }



  renderLoop() {
    this.render();
    if (Date.now() - this.timeStart < this.duration + this.delayPerPath * (this.path.length - 1) + this.delayPointsMax) {
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        this.renderLoop();
      });
    }
    else {
      this.isAnimating = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you missed last part

```
(function() {
    const elmHamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
    const gNavItems = document.querySelectorAll('.global-menu__item');
    const elmOverlay = document.querySelector('.shape-overlays');
    const overlay = new ShapeOverlays(elmOverlay);

    elmHamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (overlay.isAnimating) {
            return false;
        }
        overlay.toggle();
        if (overlay.isOpened === true) {
            elmHamburger.classList.add('is-opened-navi');
            for (var i = 0; i < gNavItems.length; i++) {
                gNavItems[i].classList.add('is-opened');
            }
        } else {
            elmHamburger.classList.remove('is-opened-navi');
            for (var i = 0; i < gNavItems.length; i++) {
                gNavItems[i].classList.remove('is-opened');
            }
        }
    });
}());
```

There is event listener `click` attached to button `elmHamburger`, That is executing anonymous arrow function. If you want to run that animation on load, you need to replace `click` event with `load`.
That is:

`elmHamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {...};`

with

`window.document.addEventListener('load', () => {...};`

If you want to start animation on load and keep button event, then

```
(function() {
    const elmHamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
    const gNavItems = document.querySelectorAll('.global-menu__item');
    const elmOverlay = document.querySelector('.shape-overlays');
    const overlay = new ShapeOverlays(elmOverlay);

    const func = () => {
        if (overlay.isAnimating) {
            return false;
        }
        overlay.toggle();
        if (overlay.isOpened === true) {
            elmHamburger.classList.add('is-opened-navi');
            for (var i = 0; i < gNavItems.length; i++) {
                gNavItems[i].classList.add('is-opened');
            }
        } else {
            elmHamburger.classList.remove('is-opened-navi');
            for (var i = 0; i < gNavItems.length; i++) {
                gNavItems[i].classList.remove('is-opened');
            }
        }
    }

    elmHamburger.addEventListener('click', func);
    window.addEventListener('load', func);
}());
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. 
Can you tell me, how i start the animation and close the Animation?

When I load the page, the animation is about all content. 
Thanks.

Comment: If you kept event listener for button, as I have written in last example, then to start animation you need to click menu button.

Comment: I used:
 window.document.addEventListener('load', () => {...};
to load the animation by load the site.
And i try to clode the animation.